# Overriding cast type on pivot model

Tags: php, laravel

I have below model:

`Document.php`

```php
/**
 * Get all of the documents field content.
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function fields()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Field::class, 'fieldable')
    ->using('App\FieldablePivot')
    ->withPivot(['content', 'type'])
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

That's using a Pivot model called `FieldablePivot`, where I need to access return the `content` column.

This is my `FieldablePivot`, where I have overwritten the `getCastType` method:

```php
protected function getCastType($key)
{
    if ($key == 'content' && !empty($this->type)) {
        return $this->type;
    }
    return parent::getCastType($key);
}
```

Below is the rows of `fieldables`:

```
id | name          | content       | type    |
---------------------------------------------
1  | field_one     | [somearray]   | array   |
2  | field_two     | somestring    | string  |
```

However, when I access a document and it's fields to get the content of a field, like:

```
@foreach ($document->fields as $field)
{{dd($field->pivot->content)}}
@endforeach
```

It returns the first one as a string (even though the type is of array):

```
"[somearray]"
```

Comment: Did you set `$type`?

Comment: @Jerodev where should that be set? `type` is a column in my database.

Comment: My bad, didn't see that. Have you tried debugging if `$this->type` is actually set when in the function?

Comment: If I do `dd($field->pivot)` it returns both the `content` and the `type` columns.

Comment: Further, if I just add `return 'array';` to the `getCastType($key)` method, it still returns a string - but if I use the `protected $casts` on the pivot model, it returns an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override the [`hasCast`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L522) function as well to make sure Eloquent knows there is a cast for this column.

```
public function hasCast($key, $types = null)
{
    if ($key === 'content') {
        return true;
    }
    return parent::hasCast($key, $types);
}
```

If you don't, and the field is not in the `$casts` array, Eloquent will not detect that the attribute has a cast.

Comment: does this affect when inserting into the database? Because when I try to insert into the database, I get error `A four digit year could not be found Data missing`